# Getting negative rate for specific set of values in numpy rate function

Tags: python, numpy, rate

I am new to `numpy` and using `numpy.rate()` to calculate APR for flat interest rate monthly payment loans.

```
no_of_month = 24
payment = 8584
loan_amount = 50000
apr = rate(no_of_month,-payment,loan_amount,0.0) *12
```

The `apr` is calculated to be `-22.816` but the actual value should be `2.0102`*(calculated in `LibreOffice Calc`)*

For `no_of_month = 23` the `apr` is `2.00079` but for `no_of_month = 24` the `apr` is `-22.816`

Following are my current guess on why this happens (They may be wrong)

- Because the duration touches multiple of 12 (another whole year)
- Some limitation to in `numpy.rate` for certain range

I can't find any related resource for either.

What is the root cause and how to fix this?

**Range for the values**

```
no_of_month - 1 to 36
payment - 1000 to 1000000
loan_amount - 10000 to 10000000
```

*All combination is possible*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

np.rate returns the interest rate that solves a polynomial equation with x**24. This has 24 solutions, some of which may be duplicated, some of which may be complex.  In the case of this particular data:

```
pv = 50000
payment = 8584 
mpr= np.rate(24, -payment, pv, 0.0)
np.pv(mpr, 24, payment)
# -49999.999999789325  This represents the 50000 pv 
mpr
# -1.901406995298687  #  mpr = -190.1% per month!

mpr1 = np.rate(24, -payment, pv, 0.0, guess = .15)
# guess lets you change the starting point for the search
mpr1
# 0.16750654293672343  # mar = 16.8% per month
np.pv(mpr1, 24, payment)
# -49999.99999999999

def apr(mpr, periods = 12):
    """  apr is ( 1 + monthly_rate ) ** 12 - 1 """
    return (1+mpr)**periods-1

apr(apr)
# -0.7122263079633477  apr = -71.2%

apr(mpr1)
# 5.4137477809069345  apr of 541.4%
```

i.e. Both 16.8% and -190.1% are mathematically correct solutions to the equations.  -190.1% doesn't make much sense in a financial context.

It's perhaps easier to understand for two periods.

```
loan_amount = 10
payment = 6
n_periods = 2

Solve 10 - 6r -6r**2
r = (6 +-sqrt(36-4*(-6)*10))/(2*-6)
r = -1.8844373105 and 0.8844373105

r = 1/(1+i) where i is the interest rate
i = 1/r - 1

r = -1.8844373105 
1/r-1
# -1.5306623862879625

r1 = 0.8844373105
1/r1-1
# 0.13066238627435212   

mpr = np.rate(2, -payment, loan_amount, 0.0)
mpr
# 0.13066238629183413

mpr1 = np.rate(2, -payment, loan_amount, 0.0, guess = -1.5)
mpr1
# -1.5306623862918336
```

There are two rates that numpy will solve for in this case which come from the two roots to the quadratic equation.

This probably doesn't help but does explain why `np.rate` (and `np.irr`) can solve to unexpected answers.

**Edit:**

I realised that if r = 1/(1 + interest_rate) there will only be one real positive solution for r.  This is the solution that generally has the most business meaning.

```
import numpy as np
"""
    To simplify the analysis let 
        r = 1 / ( 1 + interest_rate )
        p = periodic payments
        n = number of periods
    then:
        pv = loan - p*r - p*r**2 - ... -p*r**n
        dpv/dr =  -p -2*p*r - ... -p*n*r**(n-1)
        If r > 0 and p > 0 dpv/dr is negative
        Therefore there is at most one solution to pv == 0 for r > 0.
        pv == loan when r == 0
        For large r -p*r**n will dominate and pv will be negative.
        Therefore there will be one positive real solution to pv == 0
"""

def polynomial_from(nper, loan, pay): 
    """ Create numpy array to represent the polynomial """
    return np.array([-pay]*nper+[loan])

# np.roots returns one root per nper.  Filter to real roots only.
def real_roots(poly):
    roots_ = np.roots(poly)
    return roots_[np.isclose(roots_.imag, 0)].real
    # return the real part of the roots- with a zero imaginary part

def feasible_rate(nper, loan, pay):
    poly = polynomial_from(nper, loan, pay)
    reals = real_roots(poly)
    r = reals[reals>0][0]   # r is the real root > 0
    return 1/r - 1

def apr(int_rate, nperiods = 12):
    return ( 1 + int_rate ) ** nperiods - 1

mpr = feasible_rate( 24, 50000, 8584 )
print( 'Monthly rate: {:%}, Annual Rate: {:%}'.format(mpr, apr(mpr)) )
# Monthly rate: 16.750654%, Annual Rate: 541.374778%
```

Comment: Good answer, but can you also explain how the asker could achieve the desired result?

Comment: @Trilarion There's no mathematical logic to decide which is the 'right' answer.  By choosing different values for guess sometimes different answers will be generated.  If somebody wants to use numpy (as opposed to a spreadsheet) they are probably not expecting to inspect each result for feasibility.  `np.roots` may help identify all the solutions.  A separate algorithm could choose from the real solutions (as opposed to the complex solutions) in a feasible range. The business customer would have to advise what is appropriate for them.

Comment: @Trilarion I've identified a most 'business sense' solution.  See edit at the end of my answer.

Comment: @TlsChris Have played around with the `guess` parameter with most of the possible combination and have chosen the value that works for all.